# Difference between Tomcat's "Catalina service" and "Servlet Engine"

Tags: java, tomcat, catalina

I used to think that Catalina in Tomcat is a Servlet Container (which is the same as Web Container - a component meant to process Servlets + JSP).

But I saw in Tomcat startup logs that Tomcat has "Catalina service" and "Servlet Engine". So **what is the difference between Tomcat's "Catalina service" and "Servlet Engine"?**

```
дек 01, 2018 8:29:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
дек 01, 2018 8:29:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

Tomcat JSP engine is called Jasper. Tomcat startup info logs clearly state two entities both dealing with servlets, not jsp - "Catalina service" and "Servlet Engine".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tomcat engine](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Engine.html) represents the entire Catalina servlet engine that shouldn't be used in parallel to Apache server:

> An Engine is a Container that represents the entire Catalina servlet engine. It is useful in the following types of scenarios:
>   You wish to use Interceptors that see every single request processed by the entire engine.
>   You wish to run Catalina in with a standalone HTTP connector, but still want support for multiple virtual hosts.
>   In general, **you would not use an Engine when deploying Catalina connected to a web server** (such as Apache),

Catalina is the [main service of Tomcat server](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-catalina)

> Tomcat is actually composed of a number of components, including a Tomcat JSP engine and a variety of different connectors, but its core component is called Catalina. Catalina provides Tomcat's actual implementation of the servlet specification; when you start up your Tomcat server, you're actually starting Catalina.